# How do I get statistics about my recoll index?

Tags: recoll

I recently installed recoll and its Unity lens, and started indexing most of my home drive.
Photos, Documents, music, sourcecode, everything.

It is still running (no surprise there) and I would like to know how big the index is now.
 But neither `recoll` nor `recollindex` seem to give a command line option to display statistics about the index, and I didn't find an option in the GUI either.

How do I get statistics about the index?

Comment: May be the only way is to check `idxstatus.txt` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get raw statistics about the index size by checking the size of the index directory, by default ~/.recoll/xapiandb: *du ~/.recoll/xapiandb*

With a recent Recoll version, you can also get more structured statistics from the Recoll GUI: open the "Term explorer" tool (yes I know, not too intuitive...), and choose the "Index statistics" entry from the top dropdown list

Comment: Whoohaa, my index for ~400K documents is bordering 4GB :P